# Finding out the position of a GridView child given the View?

Tags: android, android-gridview

In the recently introduced `RecyclerView`, there's `getChildPosition(View)` method which returns the position of the passed `View` (or -1 if it's not a child of said `RecyclerView`).

Is there a similar method for `GridView`?

Comment: getPositionForView()

Comment: That's it! Could've sworn I looked up all the method docs multiple times. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out (thanks to @pskink) `GridView` *does* have this kind of method: `getPositionForView()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map in the adapter to store the relationship of position with the view